# Fatal Exception MailerClient Play 2.5

Tags: java, email, akka, mailer, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to send an email from my Play application. 
The Email object is prepared by another class and passed to the controller that will send off the email. When attempting to send the email however a fatal exception is thrown. 
My Controller is set up like this:

```
public class UserController extends BaseController<User> {

@Inject
MailerClient mailerClient;

@Inject
public UserController(MailerClient client) {
    super(new UserService());
    mailerClient = client;
}

public Result create(){
    resourceForm = formFactory.form(User.class);
    Form<User> filledForm = resourceForm.bindFromRequest();
    if(filledForm.hasErrors()){
        return badRequest(filledForm.errorsAsJson());
    }
    User user = filledForm.get();
    Map emailMap = new HashMap<>();
    emailMap.put("email" , user.email);
    List<User> existingUser = service.where(emailMap);
    if(existingUser.size() != 0){
        return JsonResponse.JsonMessage(BAD_REQUEST , "This Email is already registered");
    }else{
        user.status = getStatus(DORMANT);
        user.save();
        UserRegistration registration = new UserRegistration(user);
        registration.save();

        Email email = EmailDispatcher.buildEmail(ACTIVATION , user.email , registration.link);
        mailerClient.send(email);

    }
    return ok(Json.toJson(user));
}
```

My Email Configuration is set up as:

```
play.mailer{
  host = "smtp.gmail.com"
  port = 465
  ssl = yes
  user = "example.dev@gmail.com"
  password = password
}
```

Invoking `mailerClient.send(email)` as in my Controller causes the following exception to be thrown:

```
[error] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught fatal error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down ActorSystem [application]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.api.PlayConfig.getOptional(Ljava/lang/String;Lplay/api/ConfigLoader;)Lscala/Option;
        at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer.instance$lzycompute(MailerPlugin.scala:92)
        at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer.instance(MailerPlugin.scala:88)
        at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:109)
        at play.api.libs.mailer.MailerClient$class.send(MailerPlugin.scala:44)
        at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:83)
        at controllers.api.UserController.create(UserController.java:57)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Routes.scala:242)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Routes.scala:242)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:157)
        at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:156)
```

I am using Mailer version 3.0.1, my build.sbt is below:

```
name := """API"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      javaJdbc,
      cache,
      javaWs,
      "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.16",
      "de.svenkubiak" % "jBCrypt" % "0.4",
      "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "3.0.1"
    )
```

I have been unable to find a similar issue elsewhere

Comment: What plugin version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.0.1, I updated the question to show it.

Comment: They have released a new version. I use `"com.typesafe.play" % "play-mailer_2.11" % "5.0.0-M1"` and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Change your version to 5.0.0-M1

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.38",
  "de.svenkubiak" % "jBCrypt" % "0.4",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "5.0.0-M1"
)
```

I just solved it from a few minutes like this, and you late like 1 version, there was 4.0.0-M1 and new release for 4.0.0 for play 2.4, but 5.0.0-M1 for play 2.5, the play-mailer updated from like 26 days ago from today.

Edit:
version 5.0.0 released you can use it :

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "5.0.0"
```